# MQL4インジケーターのサインがリペイントしないようにしたい

Tags: mql4

MQL4インジケーターのサインが1分から5分に変えてまた1分に戻した時に
サインが消えてる場合があります。
ソースコードで自分なりにリペイントしないようにしたつもりなのですが
リペイントします。

ソースコードでどこを変更すればリペイントしないようになりますか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
bool Gi_100 = FALSE;
bool Gi_104 = FALSE;
bool Gi_108 = FALSE;
bool Gi_112 = FALSE;
int Gi_116 = 0;
bool Gi_120 = FALSE;
bool Gi_124 = FALSE;

// E37F0136AA3FFAF149B351F6A4C948E9
int init() {
SetIndexStyle(0, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY, 1);
SetIndexArrow(0, 241);
SetIndexBuffer(0, G_ibuf_76); 
SetIndexStyle(1, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY, 1);
SetIndexArrow(1, 242);
SetIndexBuffer(1, G_ibuf_80); 
return (0);
}

// 52D46093050F38C27267BCE42543EF60
int deinit() {
return (0);
}

// EA2B2676C28C0DB26D39331A336C6B92
int start() {
int Li_8;
double ima_12;
double ima_20;
double ima_28;
double ima_36;
double ima_44;
double ima_52;
double irsi_60;
double irsi_68;
double irsi_76;
double Ld_84;
double Ld_92;
int Li_100 = IndicatorCounted();
if (Li_100 < 0) return (-1);
if (Li_100 > 0) Li_100--;
int Li_0 = Bars - Li_100;
for (int Li_4 = 0; Li_4 <= Li_0; Li_4++) {
Li_8 = Li_4;
Ld_84 = 0;
Ld_92 = 0;
for (Li_8 = Li_4; Li_8 <= Li_4 + 9; Li_8++) Ld_92 += MathAbs(High[Li_8] - Low[Li_8]);
Ld_84 = Ld_92 / 10.0;
ima_12 = iMA(NULL, 0, FasterEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4);
ima_28 = iMA(NULL, 0, FasterEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 1);
ima_44 = iMA(NULL, 0, FasterEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 - 1);
ima_20 = iMA(NULL, 0, SlowerEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4);
ima_36 = iMA(NULL, 0, SlowerEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 1);
ima_52 = iMA(NULL, 0, SlowerEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 - 1);
irsi_60 = iRSI(NULL, 0, RSIPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4);
irsi_68 = iRSI(NULL, 0, RSIPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 1);
irsi_76 = iRSI(NULL, 0, RSIPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 - 1);
if (irsi_60 > 45.0 && irsi_68 < 45.0 && irsi_76 > 45.0) {
Gi_104 = TRUE;
Gi_112 = FALSE;
}
if (irsi_60 < 55.0 && irsi_68 > 55.0 && irsi_76 < 55.0) {
Gi_104 = FALSE;
Gi_112 = TRUE;
}
if (ima_12 > ima_20 && ima_28 < ima_36 && ima_44 > ima_52) {
Gi_100 = TRUE;
Gi_108 = FALSE;
}
if (ima_12 < ima_20 && ima_28 > ima_36 && ima_44 < ima_52) {
Gi_100 = FALSE;
Gi_108 = TRUE;
}
if (Gi_100 == TRUE && Gi_104 == TRUE && Gi_116 != 1) {
G_ibuf_76[Li_4] = Low[Li_4] - 0.8 * Ld_84;
if (Li_4 <= 2 && Alerts && (!Gi_120)) {
Alert(Symbol(), " ", Period(), " Signal:BUY! ");
PlaySound(Symbol()+".wav");
Gi_120 = TRUE;
Gi_124 = FALSE;
}
Gi_116 = 1;
} else {
if (Gi_108 == TRUE && Gi_112 == TRUE && Gi_116 != 2) {
G_ibuf_80[Li_4] = High[Li_4] + 0.8 * Ld_84;
if (Li_4 <= 2 && Alerts && (!Gi_124)) {
Alert(Symbol(), " ", Period(), " Signal:SELL! ");
PlaySound(Symbol()+".wav");
Gi_124 = TRUE;
Gi_120 = FALSE;
}
Gi_116 = 2;
}
}
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/140733

Comment: 質問内容がマルチポストとのご指摘を受けましたが、マルチポストがルール違反だと言うのは知りませんでした。今後は、正しく質問サイトを利用できるように注意します。

Comment: いいえ、禁止されていませんし、ルール違反ではないです。回答しようとする人への情報提供ですのでお気になさらず。metaがご参考になれば幸いです。 http://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418

Answer (score 0):

ざっと見た感じ、下記の部分が気になったので修正してみました。
 1. IndicatorCounted()が0または1を返したときに、Li_0がBarsになるため、Li_4が範囲外になる。
 2. Li_8がBars以上になり、範囲外になる。

```
for (int Li_4 = 0; Li_4 < Li_0; Li_4++) {
Li_8 = Li_4;
Ld_84 = 0;
Ld_92 = 0;
for (Li_8 = Li_4; Li_8 <= Li_4 + 9; Li_8++) { if (Li_8 < Bars) { Ld_92 += MathAbs(High[Li_8] - Low[Li_8]); } }
```

追記:毎回全部計算するようにして、無理やりリペイントしないように改造してみました。
ただし、
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/fai_fx/20100324/1269363902
にも書かれているように、あまり意味はないと思います。

```
bool Gi_120 = FALSE;
bool Gi_124 = FALSE;

// E37F0136AA3FFAF149B351F6A4C948E9
int init() {
SetIndexStyle(0, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY, 1);
SetIndexArrow(0, 241);
SetIndexBuffer(0, G_ibuf_76);
SetIndexEmptyValue(0,0); 
SetIndexStyle(1, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY, 1);
SetIndexArrow(1, 242);
SetIndexBuffer(1, G_ibuf_80);
SetIndexEmptyValue(1,0); 
return (0);
}

// 52D46093050F38C27267BCE42543EF60
int deinit() {
return (0);
}

// EA2B2676C28C0DB26D39331A336C6B92
int start() {
int Li_8;
double ima_12;
double ima_20;
double ima_28;
double ima_36;
double ima_44;
double ima_52;
double irsi_60;
double irsi_68;
double irsi_76;
double Ld_84;
double Ld_92;
bool Gi_100 = FALSE;
bool Gi_104 = FALSE;
bool Gi_108 = FALSE;
bool Gi_112 = FALSE;
int Gi_116 = 0;
//int Li_100 = IndicatorCounted();
int Li_100 = 0;
if (Li_100 < 0) return (-1);
if (Li_100 > 0) Li_100--;
int Li_0 = Bars - Li_100;
//for (int Li_4 = 0; Li_4 < Li_0; Li_4++) {
for (int Li_4 = Li_0 - 1; Li_4 >= 0; Li_4--) {
Li_8 = Li_4;
Ld_84 = 0;
Ld_92 = 0;
G_ibuf_76[Li_4] = 0;
G_ibuf_80[Li_4] = 0;
for (Li_8 = Li_4; Li_8 <= Li_4 + 9; Li_8++) { if (Li_8 < Bars) { Ld_92 += MathAbs(High[Li_8] - Low[Li_8]); } }
Ld_84 = Ld_92 / 10.0;
ima_12 = iMA(NULL, 0, FasterEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 1);
ima_28 = iMA(NULL, 0, FasterEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 2);
ima_44 = iMA(NULL, 0, FasterEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 0);
ima_20 = iMA(NULL, 0, SlowerEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 1);
ima_36 = iMA(NULL, 0, SlowerEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 2);
ima_52 = iMA(NULL, 0, SlowerEMA, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 0);
irsi_60 = iRSI(NULL, 0, RSIPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 1);
irsi_68 = iRSI(NULL, 0, RSIPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 2);
irsi_76 = iRSI(NULL, 0, RSIPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE, Li_4 + 0);
if (irsi_60 > 45.0 && irsi_68 < 45.0 && irsi_76 > 45.0) {
Gi_104 = TRUE;
Gi_112 = FALSE;
}
if (irsi_60 < 55.0 && irsi_68 > 55.0 && irsi_76 < 55.0) {
Gi_104 = FALSE;
Gi_112 = TRUE;
}
if (ima_12 > ima_20 && ima_28 < ima_36 && ima_44 > ima_52) {
Gi_100 = TRUE;
Gi_108 = FALSE;
}
if (ima_12 < ima_20 && ima_28 > ima_36 && ima_44 < ima_52) {
Gi_100 = FALSE;
Gi_108 = TRUE;
}
if (Gi_100 == TRUE && Gi_104 == TRUE && Gi_116 != 1) {
G_ibuf_76[Li_4] = Low[Li_4] - 0.8 * Ld_84;
if (Li_4 <= 2 && Alerts && (!Gi_120)) {
Alert(Symbol(), " ", Period(), " Signal:BUY! ");
PlaySound(Symbol()+".wav");
Gi_120 = TRUE;
Gi_124 = FALSE;
}
Gi_116 = 1;
} else {
if (Gi_108 == TRUE && Gi_112 == TRUE && Gi_116 != 2) {
G_ibuf_80[Li_4] = High[Li_4] + 0.8 * Ld_84;
if (Li_4 <= 2 && Alerts && (!Gi_124)) {
Alert(Symbol(), " ", Period(), " Signal:SELL! ");
PlaySound(Symbol()+".wav");
Gi_124 = TRUE;
Gi_120 = FALSE;
}
Gi_116 = 2;
}
}
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。修正した部分を変更したのですが、一時期改善したかと思ったのですが、1分から5分に変えてまた1分に戻した時に、サインの位置がずれてたり、あとなかったサインが表示されました。回答の方よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 詳しくは見ていないのですが、ima_44とima_52の算出時に未来の足を見ているため、時間軸を切り替えて再計算されたときに結果が変わって消える場合はあるかもしれません。また、時間軸の切替時にIndicatorCounted()が複数回0を返す場合がありますが、そのときにGi_100～Gi_116に前回の値が残ったまま再計算されて結果が変わっているかもしれません。

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。何か良い改善策はないでしょうか？どのようにコードを修正すればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 無理やりですが、リペイントしないようにしたコードを追記しました。未来の足も見ないようにしています。

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。コードまで有り難うございます。追加してもらったコードを試したのですがリペイントしませんでした。でもロジックは変わってしまうのですね。